# Access Keycloak Admin API through a proxy or directly from a single page app?

Tags: keycloak

I have a SPA, a backend REST API and Keycloak as the identity server.

For Admin functionality of the Site I need to access the Keycloak Admin API, now I am wondering if it would be best or even possible to directly access the Keycloak API from the SPA with the token of the currently logged in admin or if it would be better to create endpoints at my backend API that then act as a proxy for the Keycloak Admin API.

It seems kind of hard to get any good information on the Keycloak REST API besides the endpoint definitions. So I am unsure if a normal admin token even satisfies the authentication of the API and if so what is has to look like since you can modify the JWT payload quite a bit and I tried to minimize it as much as possible.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. What kind of Keycloak REST API? That "standard" OIDC login/authorize "API" or Keycloak Admin API?

Comment: @JanGaraj Oh im sorry, im talking about the Admin API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear answer. It really depends on your security awareness and what kind of security risk are you able to accept. I known instances where Keycloak Admin API is behind Nginx reverse proxy with required mutual TLS authentication. So there is additional auth method (TLS client cert) on top of existing Keycloak auth just to make it harder for bad guys.

I would say direct access from SPA will be easy to implement (if you are able to sort all potential CORS issues), but proxying through backend gives you better options for audit of requests on the app level.